# Conditional formatting comparing one table to another

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

Comparing one months table with previous month, and was looking to add conditional formatting where I compare this months incidents per state to last months incidents in each state, and if there is an increase in 10% or more incidents, then change the cell to Red, and if there is reduction in 10% or more then change to green, and if it is between those two numbers then yellow.

Is the only way to add 3 separate rules to each cell individually, and if so how do you do that?
Otherwise is there a quicker way?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: So set up the rules on the template. Then get the two data blocks to call in the latest month and previous month automatically. All you need to to then is add the fresh data...

Comment: Select the three May rows from bottom to top, then apply the custom formatting rule for the top cell (with all three cells still selected) usuning the formulas option (So, `= B3 >= B8*1.1`). The formula will be automatically adjusted for the other two cells.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I don't know if it can be done with a single CF rule but I made three CF rules based on formula, one for each color:

Red color formula: `=B3-B9>=0.1*B9`

Green Color formula: `=B3-B9<=-0.1*B9`

Yellow color formula: `=AND(B3-B9<0.1*B9;B3-B9>-0.1*B9)`

If I change May values, colors update:

[image]